# preg_match expressão regular para pegar texto entre tag

Tags: preg-match

Qual seria a expressão  do preg_match para pegar o texto "sair" dentro da seguinte tag?

```html
<a href="/logout" role="menuitem">
                            <i class="icon-key"></i> Sair
                        </a>
```

Comment: Expressão regular para tratar HTML não é a melhor solução. Que linguagem pretende fazer isso? PHP? Se sim, use a classe `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Como não temos informações sobre onde, como ou o porquê de o OP precisar fazer isso, usar a `DOMDocument` apenas pra isso seria cono matar uma formiga com umabalade canhão

Comment: @BrunoAugusto neste caso, você nem saberia que é uma formiga, então levar um canhão seria apropriado. Digo isso porquê se o HTML variar em qualquer detalhe, a expressão regular é invalidada e a aplicação para de funcionar. E para um HTML mudar é muito fácil...

Comment: Davi não atirou qualquer pedra no Golias. Foi escolhida a ferramenta mais adequada para a tarefa. Pra uma coisa simples assim a [SimpleXml](http://php.net/SimpleXml) dá e sobra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão ficaria assim:

```
<a href="\/logout" role="menuitem">[\s]+<i class="icon-key"><\/i> ([a-zA-Z]+)[\s]+<\/a>
```